# My new keyboard doesn't have a pipe key

Tags: keyboard-layout

i just bought a keyboard. I had notice the lack of the ? / keys, but i was able to type then using the "alt gr+q" "alt gr + w". Didn't like, but it was ok.

Today i was going to do something in the terminal, and i was suprised with the lack of a pipe key, and i found out that ANY keyboard combination works!
should be win+l, but that make nothing. "alt gr + l does a useless crossed l" (lł) (its an lowercase L)

[image: This is the keyboard]
[image: System keyboard layout]

Does anyone have a clue on how i can fix this?

Comment: If the crossed L is useless to you, then that would be a good candidate for remapping to `|` with `xmodmap(1)`

Comment: That's kind of a bummer because it looks really cool.

Comment: How do i change only the "alternative" key with xmodmap? I workaround it mapping the menu key (which i cant remember ever using it) to the missing "? l". And how do i make this permanent? i am on fed23 on this machine, rc.local doesn't exists.

Comment: That's a keyboard? Looks more like a sunlamp.

Comment: It is a pity that there is not, as far as I can tell from looking around, an ABNT2 (107-key) version of that keyboard, as well as this U.S. (104-key) version.  That would have made your life a lot easier.  Even a "European" (105-key) version would have made your life better, as the extra key is exactly the key that you are so sorely missing.  You have put your finger on, or rather _not_ put your finger on, one of the very reasons that a 107-key ABNT Windows keyboard is an improvement on a 104-key ABNT Windows keyboard.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot I would suspect AltGr+Shift+i.